# elasticsearch : merge 2 fields from different types in search result

Tags: elasticsearch

Do you know if we can merge dynamically 2 fields which belong to different types in one unique field

I have an index `my_index` with 2 types `type1` and `type2`

I am doing a search on those 2 types :

```
POST /my_index/_search
{
  "min_score": 1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "titreType1": {
              "query": "boy"

        }
      }
    },
    {
      "match": {
        "titreType2": {
          "query": "boy"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
  }
}
```

I will have results from the 2 different types that looks like to:

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "type1",
        "_id": "AVo0LhFj8N13TOVDqMo9",
        "_score": 13.171456,
        "_source": {
          "titreType1": "the boy !"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "type1",
        "_id": "AVo0Lg5X8N13TOVDqMUH",
        "_score": 12.986091,
        "_source": {
          "titreType1": "if i were a boy"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "type2",
        "_id": "AVo0S-nM8N13TOVDqNPX",
        "_score": 12.34135,
        "_source": {
          "titreType2": "boy are very nasty and it is sad"
        }
      },
...
]
```

I would like to have in my result just one column named "title" that display value from titreType1 or titreType2

Do you know how to do this?